# IQ Test question - numbers inside a 4x3 grid

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I could not solve a question from an online IQ test:

[image]

Transcription of image:
What is the number in the * cell?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 38 | 47 | 4 |
| 6 | 35 | 42 | * |
| 12 | 21 | 23 | 27 |

The options were:
10, -5, 32 and 18

The only pattern that I managed to find was that the numbers went in an odd-even sequence(that means, odd-even-odd-even or even-odd-even-odd), so the missing number would be odd. The only odd number is -5, so the answer is -5. However, I don't really think that this is possible since there aren't any negative numbers in the grid, and even if it is, there must be a better way of solving. Can someone tell me what is the correct answer and reasoning? Thank you.

Source: [Arealme IQ Test](https://www.arealme.com/iq/en/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> -5

Reasoning

> Adding the digits in each cell, we get
>  9  11  11   4
>  6    8    6   *
>  3    3    5   9
>  And now the first row is the sum of the second and third rows so the missing number is **-5**.

Comment: How do you think like this? This is terribly unconventional I suppose. Difficult if you haven't looked at a similar problem before.